# Definition of "Diabatic" vs "Diathermic"

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, terminology

In Atkins' *Elements of Physical Chemistry (Sixth Edition)* it is written that:

> walls that permit heating as a mode of transfer of energy are called diathermic

and that the converse situation is given the label *adiabatic*.

Do the words *adiathermic* or *diabatic* have any meaning, and if so, how do they differ from the two above?

Comment: In thermodynamics we use  adiabatic to mean impassible to heat, i.e. a process in which no heat enters or leaves. Diathermy means 'heating through' and does not seem to be that commonly used. We could use non-adiabatic and diabatic instead but its unusual in thermodynamics. The terms diabatic, adiabatic & non-adiabatic  are usually used in the context of reaction dynamics / quantum mechanics and unfortunately their usage is not entirely consistent in the literature. I don't recall seeing 'adiathemic'

Comment: Pippard in his amazingly clear exposition of thermodynamics uses the adjective "adiathermic" for an arbitrary process without heat exchange and "adiabatic"  as a process that is "adiathermic" + "reversible".